# SQL Mirroring FailingOver from Principal times out

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, mirroring

I have the following code:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                string Command = string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [AdventureWorks2014].[Person].[Address]");
                using (SqlConnection mConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SQL1.mike.local;Failover Partner=SQL2.mike.local;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks2014;User Id=sa;Password=***************; "))
                {
                    mConnection.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand myCmd = new SqlCommand(Command, mConnection))
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = myCmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(reader.GetInt32(0));
                        }
                    }
                    mConnection.Close();
                }
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I run the console app, and manually failover the database within sql server management studio.

The app which is running just stops writing lines to the console, and after about 30 seconds, it fails with this exception:

> Unhandled Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A
>   network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing
>   a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not
>   accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>   ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The network path was not found

I do exactly the same thing, but failing back over from the failover partner, back to the original principal, and it works as expected. No error messages or exceptions, it just gracefully fails over and continues printing lines to the console.

What could be the problem? Why doesn't it fail over gracefully from the principal?

Comment: Verify Remote connection enabled, firewall is disabled at partner or you added exception for SQL Server port in firewall and TCP/IP is enabled at mirror server. If all these are Ok verify the database failed over to mirror properly (completely recovered).

Comment: have you completed the failover from the principal to the partner where it works, and then attempt to fail back *while* leaving the program run?

Comment: @SeanGallardy, it doesn't work when failing back over to the partner. What I have done instead is wrote a service that detects the mirror failover and updates the DNS record. Works as expected. This means I don't need to update all the connection strings for all my apps!